# Deleting folders using os.remove() in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to delete multiple folders mentioned in list `N` using `os.remove()` but I see an error. How can I fix it?

```
import os

N=[1,3]

for i in N:
    os.remove(rf"C:\Users\User\Test1\{i}")
```

The error is

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Test1\\1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do with `shutil` module:

```py
import shutil
N=[1,3]

for i in N:
    shutil.rmtree(rf"C:\Users\User\Test1\{i}")
```